# History behind the word pressure

Tags: biographical-details

I want to know who had used the word pressure for the first time and what was the reason for him to use the word pressure.
As I searched on google but it is only showing about barometer discovery

Comment: This word was not invented. The old Latin root (*pressus*) was used because it meant "pressing" without any specific relation to air or barometers. In the case of atmospheric pressure it was simply the air that did the pressing. "*Literal meaning "act or fact of pressing" in a physical sense is attested from early 15c... Scientific sense in physics is from 1650s*", see [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pressure).

Answer (score -1):

From my prospect the word pressure has been used since Aristotle's time but they were not calling it pressure but instead of that they were calling it weight of something been applied on something like water pressure as water is applying its weight on glass tube